# Not getting output from database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3.1.3, and want to display data from database, but following output display message occurs:

```
CI_DB_pdo_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => PDO Object
        (
        )

    [result_id] => PDOStatement Object
        (
            [queryString] => SELECT *
FROM `Tbl_Post`
        )

[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 
[row_data] =>
```

)

--my connection is true.
--my query i true.
--controller is true.
--model is true

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use codeigniter [Active Record Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) for your query

```
$q = $this->db->get('Tbl_Post');
    $result = $q->result();

    //to view display query result
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```